# cause of fatal error in sphinx-train tool : mk_s2sendump

Tags: speech-recognition, cmusphinx

as per the link https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutorialadapt/, performed all earlier steps successfully until trying to execute **mk_s2sendump** tool with following command-line options :

**mk_s2sendump -pocketsphinx yes -moddeffn en-us-adapt/mdef.txt -mixwfn en-us-adapt/mixture_weights -sendumpfn en-us-adapt/sendump**

provided correct mixture_weights file, but encountered fatal exception as below:

```
    FATAL: "senone.c", line 275: en-us-adapt/mixture_weights: #float32 values(13) doesn't match dimensions: 42 x 3 x 128
```

Comment: mixture_weights file is wrong, link to a proper one is provided in tutorial.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev, thanks. after linking to en-us (instead of en-us-adapt)
**-mixwfn en-us/mixture_weights**, the issue got resolved.